# Erro ao instalar o psycopg2 em um ambiente virtualenv com pypy

Tags: python, postgresql, virtualenv

Instalei o pypy da sequinte forma:

`wget https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64.tar.bz2`

`tar xf pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64.tar.bz2`

`virtualenv -p ~/pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64/bin/pypy my-pypy-env`

Ativei o ambiente

`source ~/.virtualenv/my-pypy-env/bin/activate`

Instalei alguns pacotes:

`pip install mongo`

`pip install numpy`

Mas quando vou instalar o psycopg2:

`pip install psycopg2`

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-
info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-
info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).


----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7lSMte/psycopg2/
```

Tentei instalar com sudo:

`sudo pip install psycopg2`

Mas gerou outro erro:

```
The directory '/home/prisvo/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/prisvo/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Ok, então apenas devo instalar usando -H na frente do sudo.

`sudo -H pip install psycopg2`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Parece que funcionou, mas ao testar:

`python prisvo-recommender.py`

```
  File "prisvo-recomender.py", line 1, in <module>
    import banco
  File "/home/prisvo/prisvo-recommendation/corepypy/banco.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo errado ou se o psycopg2 não roda com o pypy. Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?

Comment: Talvez precise do pacote `postgresql-server-dev`

Comment: deveria ser só postgresql-dev , no caso - vai precisar também, além da minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma pesquisa pelos pacotes revela que o psycopg2 não é compatível com o pypy (isso vai acontecer com vários pacotes Python que tenham código nativo junto, ou seja, usando a API específica do cPython). Essa informação não está em um único lugar autoritativo - achei espalhada como resposta em 2 ou 3 lugares (inclusive o site do Pypy cita que o psycopg2 seria uma exceção a regra dos pacotes compilados e que funcionaria com o pypy. Bom, tentei usar aqui com Pypy3 e não foi)

No entanto, criaram o pacote psycopg2cffi , que usa uma outra tecnologia (CFFI) para realizar as chamadas nativas as bibliotecas do postres. Esse foi instalado - mas não antes de eu ter que fazer uma manobra aqui.

Vi que você baixou o pypy3 já compilado independente da distribuição - a partir do código fonte. Provavelmente você vai precisar baixar também o código fonte dele - https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v5.10.1-src.tar.bz2 para ter os arquvos .h, se não tiver uma pasta "include" aí.
Para quem estiver usando o pypy3 da distribuição Linux, como no meu caso, primeiro precisei instalar o pacote de desenvolvimento do pypy3 - aqui é um fedora, então `sudo dnf install pypy3-devel` - suponho que em Debian e Ubuntu o comando seja `apt-get install pypy3-dev` (mas pode haver variações no nome do pacote)

Mesmo com isso, `pip install psycopg2cffi` ainda deu erro - lendo as mensagens percebi que ele não tinha localizado o arquivo de include  `pythonconfig.h` do Python. No meu sistema, esse arquivo foi colocado na  na pasta `/usr/lib64/pypy3-5.5.0/include`.  (Em outros sistemas ele vai parar em uma pasta parecida - talvez só mude o número da versão. Como você baixou o pypy3 independente do Linux, pode ser que precise baixar o código fonte dele também para ter os arquivos `.h`). Então criei uma variável de ambiente para indicar ao compilador C para incluir essa pasta de include. Foi só digitar no shell:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib64/pypy3-5.5.0/include
```

Pronto, com isso o comando `pip install psycopg2cffi` funcionou.
Se você pretende usar o psycopg2 diretamente, isso é suficiente - no seu código Python você pode tentar algo assim:

```
try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    import psycopg2cffi as psycopg2
```

(se estiver preocupado com código que funcione em ambos os ambientes, claro - senão é só colocar o segundo import direto).

Agora, se você for usar o sqlalchemy, ou algum outro framework que import o psycopg2 sem passar pelo seu código, há mais um passo: a linha contendo o `import psycopg2` não está em código sob seu controle, e vai falhar quando for execudata. No caso do SQLAlchemy o erro acotnece quando se tenta criar um engine. O jeito oficial de não acontecer é colocar na URL de conexão o que o psycopg2cffi está sendo usado - a URL toma a forma:

```
postgresql+psycopg2cffi://user:password@host:port/dbname
```

(em vez de só `postgresql://`). 
Alternativamente, você pode simplesmente enganar o framework  (se não for o sqlalchemy, ou se você quiser manter a url sem alterações). Para fazer isso, após importar o psycopg2cffi, criamos um alias "psycopg2" para o mesmo dentro de sys.modules - dessa forma, quando o Python encontrar um `import psycopg2` vai assumir que o módulo já está importado, e usar o ...cffi no lugar:

```
import psycopg2cffi
import sys
sys.modules["psycopg2"] = sys.modules["psycopg2cffi"]
```

(em tempo nunca faça `sudo pip install...` - não vai resolver nada se você estiver num virtualenv, e pode quebrar o seu sistema se você não estiver - sempre instale os pacotes de Python com o gerenciador de pacotes do sistema, (apt-get no Ubuntu). Dentro de um virtualenv você usa o pip)